# ntpdate failing "Name or service not known"

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage, ntp, ntpdate

I've got a NAS that is Linux-based (Linux version 2.6.32.11-svn70860) and it is not able to set its time using ntp.  The previous SysAdmin is long gone so I have no idea whether this problem just started happening, or whether it's been this way for years.  I'm also contacting the manufacturer, but don't have a lot of confidence in their tech support - which is why I'm here!

In /var/log/daemon.log I see lines like this:

```
Jan 13 09:28:37 ntpdate[16529]: can't find host pool.ntp.org
Jan 13 09:28:37 ntpdate[16529]: can't find host time.windows.com
Jan 13 09:28:37 ntpdate[16529]: can't find host pool.ntp.org
Jan 13 09:28:37 ntpdate[16529]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

So I started investigating ntpdate.  If I execute

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

it responds

```
Error : Name or service not known
16 Jan 09:16:38 ntpdate[22019]: can't find host pool.ntp.org
16 Jan 09:16:38 ntpdate[22019]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

but if I execute

```
ping pool.ntp.org
```

it responds

```
PING pool.ntp.org (207.32.191.59) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 207.32.191.59: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=97.1 ms
64 bytes from 207.32.191.59: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=97.0 ms
64 bytes from 207.32.191.59: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=97.4 ms
```

which makes me think the Internet connection, IP configuration, DNS, etc. are all fine.

Where do I go from here?

UPDATE 1

```
nslookup pool.ntp.org
```

returns

```
;; Got recursion not available from A.B.C.D, trying next server
Server:     205.171.2.65
Address:    205.171.2.65#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   pool.ntp.org
Address: 209.114.111.1
Name:   pool.ntp.org
Address: 173.242.114.154
Name:   pool.ntp.org
Address: 204.235.61.9
Name:   pool.ntp.org
Address: 64.6.144.6
```

A.B.C.D is an IP address inside our company, not sure why it's showing up.

UPDATE 2

I read about nslookup being deprecated in favor of dig, so I gave it a try.

```
dig pool.ntp.org

; <<>> DiG 9.5.1-P3 <<>> pool.ntp.org
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 56646
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pool.ntp.org.          IN  A
;; Query time: 50 msec
;; SERVER: A.B.C.D#53(A.B.C.D)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 16 11:03:40 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

where A.B.C.D is that same internal name server.

Comment: Is port UDP 123 (NTP) open at firewall side (if any) for outgoing connexions to Internet ?

Comment: Yeah, we have been investigating that, it looks like it's open but nobody here is an expert on the SonicWall so we're not 100% sure.  Is there a program I could run (command-line Linux is best but I could run something on a Mac or Linux or Windows too) that would check whether port 123 is open?

Comment: What is the result for `ntpdate 207.32.191.59` ?

Comment: Interesting, I think that works!  It responded "16 Jan 10:34:58 ntpdate[27038]: step time server 207.32.191.59 offset 55.843776 sec".  Is ntpdate somehow not able to talk DNS (even though clearly the connection is there since 'ping' works)?

Comment: `dig pool.ntp.org` - **`WARNING: recursion requested but not available`**  Whatever you are using for DNS servers is not doing recursive lookups.  Fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: The folks in charge of our DNS server had to enable recursion.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this then - I'm the OP, and based on the questions user2196728 and Zoredache asked I was able to ascertain that enabling recursion on the DNS server was the solution.

Comment: I guess this is the approp. way then. Perhaps you could expand what they did?

Comment: I can find out what they did, but it will be specific to one DNS server, and is kind of off-topic (since my question is about ntpdate)

Comment: I understand what you're saying but then how is this Q&A of consequence to any future visitors? If someone were to run into the same issue would this answer guide them is all I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to change **/etc/default/ntpdate** - because only n**ntpdate** package was installed:

```
NTPDATE_USE_NTP_CONF=no
```

and reboot (I suspect this is optional)

Comment: This looks like an answer to an entirely different question.

Comment: Not really, I had the same DNS ussues with ntpdate which were solved with above steps